# How to crop a 3D image when the point of interest lies on the edge of the image?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have a 3D image of size `512*512*30`. I also have a csv file with the points of interest stored in it. I want to crop a 3D volume of size `32*32*16` around the point of interest with the point at its center. Ive written the following to achieve this:

```
block = [32, 32, 16]
img = imageio.volread('path\\to\\tiff\\file')
x, y, z = 191, 303, 17
img_block = img_block[x - int(block[0] / 2):x + int(block[0] / 2),
                              y - int(block[1] / 2):y + int(block[1] / 2),
                              z - int(block[2] / 2):z + int(block[2] / 2)]
```

This works in the above case but fails when I have an x,y,z point on the edge for example at `z = 28` I get an out of bound error, which is expected.

How do I avoid this problem and ensure smooth copping?

Thanks

Comment: The answer depends a little on what you want to do with the outliers. Typical ways to deal with the issue are called "bounds-checking". You can pad your array with zeros, mirror at the border or just discard values. What works best for you?

Comment: Furthermore: If one point is in the center, the size should be rather odd than even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for padding could look like this:

```
import numpy as np

point = [0,1,2]
img = imageio.volread('path\\to\\tiff\\file')
block = [32,32,16]
img_x, img_y, img_z = img.shape
img_padded = np.pad(img, block, 'constant', constant_values=0) #lookup np.pad for other padding options
img_block = img_padded[point[0]-block[0]/2:point[0]+block[0]/2...]
```

Comment: Thanks, Ive tried padding as well. But wouldnt padding before cropping change the location of x,y,z?

Comment: This answer worked for me, but I would like to add that I would add the pad amount to my coordinate, for example, if I only padded the z-dimension using ``npad = ((0, 0), (0, 0), (10, 10))`` and ``img_padded = np.pad(img_block, pad_width=npad, mode='constant', constant_values=0)``. The this would add 10 rows before and 10 rows after in the z-dimension. So I would add 10 to the z-coordinate.

Comment: I'm adding once again that `np.pad` has more options to deal with the padded area. E.g. you can mirror or clamp the value on the edges, which makes sense if you deal with e.g. image reconstruction (to avoid abrupt changes in intensity) but doesn't make much sense for visualisation.